# How to use groupBY() and count() in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get the present and absent days of a particular user from the database.
I have joined two tables
`1 -> tbl_workers 2->tbl_attendances`

I want to get the present and absent days of every worker from the database. How can I get those records ??
I want result like below

```
[
"worker_id" :  1,
"present_days" : "10",
"absent_days" : "10",
]
```

```
 $salaryMaster = SalaryMaster::find($id);
            $startDate = $salaryMaster->salary_master_to_date;
            $endDate = $salaryMaster->salary_master_from_date;
            return $data = tbl_worker::join("salary_details", "salary_details.salary_details_worker_id", "tbl_workers.worker_id")
                ->join("tbl_attendances", "tbl_attendances.attendance_worker_id", "tbl_workers.worker_id")
                ->where("salary_details.salary_details_master_table_id", $id)
                ->whereBetween("tbl_attendances.created_at", [Carbon::parse($startDate), Carbon::parse($endDate)])
 ->select(DB::raw('tbl_attendances.attendance_worker_presense,count(*) as count'))
                ->groupBy('tbl_attendances.attendance_worker_presense')
                ->get();
```

Comment: what exactly tbl_worker is ?

Comment: `tbl_worker` contains the workers list and I have stored the the worker_id with their attendance in `tbl_attendances` table.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what data these tables really hold. Moreover, from the queries, I didn't get an idea of how your store absent days. From what I do get however, I believe this should probably help you in getting the 'worker_id' and 'present_days' in json format;

```
$salaryMaster = SalaryMaster::find($id);
$startDate = $salaryMaster->salary_master_to_date;
$endDate = $salaryMaster->salary_master_from_date;
$data = tbl_worker::join("salary_details", "salary_details.salary_details_worker_id", "tbl_workers.worker_id")
            ->join("tbl_attendances", "tbl_attendances.attendance_worker_id", "tbl_workers.worker_id")
            ->where("salary_details.salary_details_master_table_id", $id)
            ->whereBetween("tbl_attendances.created_at", [Carbon::parse($startDate), Carbon::parse($endDate)])->select('tbl_attendances.attendance_worker_presense')->count();

Return response()->json([
  ‘worker_id’ => $id, 
  ‘present_days’ => $data
]);
```